# Orange save model in python script

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, orange

I can use the "save model" functionality successfully using GUI.

```
https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/model/savemodel.html
```

I am writing a python program to run the Orange library and want to use this functionality in python.
I have searched the documentation provided by the Orange developer

```
https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/_modules/
```

but did not find a solution for my problem. 
Does anyone know how I could write a python script to use this functionality or is there a resource teaching us how to use different Orange functionalities in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just dump it using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html). This is exactly what `Save Model` and `Load Model` widgets do and that's why we do not have a scripting API for this functionality.

To save a model `model` use:

```
import pickle

with open("<filename>", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

and to load it use:

```
with open("<filename>", "rb") as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks. I can save the model now. But can I get Classification accuracy on test data using previous saved model?

Comment: I created a new post. May you take a look at it. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608130/get-classification-accuracy-on-test-data-using-previous-saved-model