# get Classification accuracy on test data using previous saved model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, orange

I am using Orange data mining tool to write a python script to get classification accuracy on test data using a previous saved model(pickle file).

```
dataFile = "training.csv" 
data = Orange.data.Table(dataFile);
learner = Orange.classification.RandomForestLearner()
cf = learner(data)
#save the pickle file
with open("1.pkcls", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(cf, f)

#load the pickle file
with open("1.pkcls", "rb") as f:
    loadCF = pickle.load(f)
testFile = "testing.csv" 
test = Orange.data.Table(testFile);

learners = [1]
learners[0] = cf
result = Orange.evaluation.testing.TestOnTestData(data,test,learners)
# get classification accuracy
CAs = Orange.evaluation.CA(result)
```

I can successfully save and load the model but I had an error

```
    CAs = Orange.evaluation.CA(result)


File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Orange/evaluation/scoring.py", line 39, in __new__
    return self(results, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Orange/evaluation/scoring.py", line 48, in __call__
    return self.compute_score(results, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Orange/evaluation/scoring.py", line 84, in compute_score
    return self.from_predicted(results, skl_metrics.accuracy_score)
  File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Orange/evaluation/scoring.py", line 75, in from_predicted
    dtype=np.float64, count=len(results.predicted))
  File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Orange/evaluation/scoring.py", line 74, in <genexpr>
    for predicted in results.predicted),
  File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 172, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/Users/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 82, in _check_targets
    "".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Can't handle mix of multiclass and continuous
```

I find a way to fix this problem and successfully generate the classification accuracy by deleting

```
cf = learner(data)
```

However, if I delete this line of code, I am unable to train a model and save it because RandomForestLearner does not train the model based on the input file before code of saving and loading model.

```
with open("1.pkcls", "wb") as f:
pickle.dump(cf, f)

#load the pickle file
with open("1.pkcls", "rb") as f:
loadCF = pickle.load(f)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to train a model first and save it as a pickle file. Then I can use it to test another file to get classification accuracy later?

Comment: are you sure the test and train data labels are the same? Also do both X values look the same? Looks like the model is complaining because of data incompatibility between the 2 sets

Comment: @omu_negru thanks for your reply. I actually used the same file as training and testing. Both files have exact same contents and just files names are different.

Comment: Can you show the true classes from `data` and `test`?

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks for your reply. Does true class mean target/label?

Comment: Yes. Post the labels from `data` as well as `test`

Comment: @ My training and testing files are the same. Labels are just "moving", "rotating", "scooping". I think the problem might be the wrong use of result = Orange.evaluation.testing.TestOnTestData(data,test,learners)  which also takes training file as input but I believe this should not be the case to still need the training file here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not pre-train the classifier before passing it to `TestOnTestData` (its name should be `TrainOnTrainAndTestOnTestData`, i.e. it invokes fitting/training step on its own).

Unfortunately there is no readily available explicit way to create a `Result` instance from an application of a pre-trained classifier(s) on a test dataset.

One quick and dirty way is to thunk the 'learners' passed to TestOnTest data to return the pre-trained models

```
results = Orange.evaluation.testing.TestOnTestData(data, test, [lambda testdata: loadCF])
```